# Query NetApp with snmpget/snmpwalk

Tags: monitoring, snmp, netapp

I have loaded the NetApp MIB file onto a linux server and I am able to snmpwalk the management interface.  However, with the MIB loaded I only seem to see results that are prefixed with either RFC1213 or SNMPv2-SMI, without the MIB these are displayed as OID values.

I was expecting to be able to see items specific to NetApp hardware such as free space on an aggregate etc.  The only snmp options on the NetApp filer seem to be related to turning snmp off/on and setting the community string.

snmpget -v2c -c public x.x.x.x sysDescr.0

## SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: NetApp Release 8.1 7-Mode: Thu Mar 29 13:56:17 PDT 2012

Does anyone have any information how to get additional snmp results other than networking information covered by RFC1213 and SNMPv2.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default snmpwalk doesn't walk the entire tree, try this:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -cpublic x.x.x.x 1
```